О грамматической образности в русском языке. Примеры грамматических тропов
Процесс приближенья к столу
сродни ожиданию пытки.
Сродни продеванию нитки
в задергавшуюся иглу.
По рельсу, лучу, по ковру,
ко рву по ковровой дорожке.
— Но только не рвись, пока врешься.
— О Господи, я и не вру.
           Еременко А.В.

Эта тема рассматривается в лингвистике, и мне она кажется интересной.
На форуме мы обсуждали стихотворение Есенина "Шаганэ ты моя, Шаганэ…" с грамматической "ошибкой", но сейчас мне кажется, что  у него в сочетании "Я готов рассказать тебе поле" использован грамматический троп: винительный падеж прямого объекта вместо предложной формы: рассказать про поле.
Вопрос: Какие примеры грамматических тропов вам встречались в современной или классической поэзии, а также в прозе.
Из статьи:
Начиная с 2000-х годов поэтика грамматических категорий выходит на передний план как при рассмотрении классических текстов, так и текстов новейшей поэзии... При этом обнаруживается тенденция к рассмотрению грамматических новообразований не как «грамматических неологизмов», а как «грамматических тропов», реализующих изобразительные и выразительные средства грамматики.

рассказать~нарисовать, воспеть. Ну да, ошибка, но звучит) В этом стихе тоже, игра слов. Рассказать сказку можно, рассказать радость, горе .. поле? ощущение поля?

Звучит, да.  Гений, что там говорить. "Эти волосы взял я у ржи..."  И весь он светлый и золотой.

Интересную тему вы подняли.

Спасибо! Напишите о тропах, если попадутся)

Одна из общих тем грамматических тропов — это подвижность категорий залога и переходности.
А что это значит?  Рассмотри два примера.
Пример 1
   Шаганэ ты моя, Шаганэ!
   Потому что я с севера, что ли,
   Я готов рассказать тебе поле,
   Про волнистую рожь при луне…
   Я готов рассказать тебе поле,
   Эти волосы взял я у ржи,
   Если хочешь, на палец вяжи –
   Я нисколько не чувствую боли. 
               С. Есенин 

Глагол рассказать  может быть переходным или непереходным: рассказать что и о чем.  Соответственно, возможна сочетаемость с прямым и косвенным дополнением.
РАССКАЗАТЬ, св. что, о ком-чём, про кого-что или с придат. дополнит. Устно сообщить, изложить что-л. Р. занимательную историю. Р. сказку, анекдот. Р. содержание книги. Р. о детстве, о жизни за границей. Р. про товарища.
Нельзя рассказать книгу, а тем более поле.  Можно рассказать о поле, про поле,  но это будет не прямой объект. Другими словами,  это будут сведения о предмете, но не его суть и внутреннее содержание. Как понять бескрайность поля, его свободу, ощущение простора! А еще  — какое оно разное, цветущее весной и золотое летом, как прекрасно и необыкновенно ночью.  И все это  поэт дает как единый поэтический образ  — рассказать поле.
Пример 2
 По рельсу, лучу, по ковру,
 ко рву по ковровой дорожке.
 — Но только не рвись, пока врешься.
 — О Господи, я и не вру.
       Еременко А.В.

Возвратность тесно связана с категорией залога, при этом возвратные глаголы различаются между собой по активности/пассивности субъекта и объекта.
Врать — переходный глагол.
ВРАТЬ, нсв. Разг. 1. (св. соврать и наврать). (что). Говорить неправду; сочинять небылицы; лгать, обманывать. Не верьте ему, он врёт.
Есть еще безличная форма: ВРАТЬСЯ, врётся; вралось; нсв. безл. (обычно с отриц.). Разг. О стремлении, желании врать. Хотел ещё соврать, да что-то не врётся.
Но поэт использует личную форму глагола: пока (ты) врешься, то есть пишешь что-либо. Что же означает возвратный глагол?  Есть несколько значений у возвратного залога, а здесь, вероятно, общевозвратное.
ОБЩЕВОЗВРАТНОЕ (действие совершается в самом субъекте; глаголы обозначают психическое или физическое состояние субъекта): сердиться, радоваться, удивляться, торопиться, стараться, надеяться, останавливаться, кланяться, пениться;
Писатель не просто пишет:  он сам и его творчество  —  как нечто единое.
 Каждый пишет, что он слышит,
 Каждый слышит, как он дышит,
 Как он дышит, так и пишет,
 Не стараясь угодить...
              Б. Окуджава


Кстати говоря, форма второго лица сослагательного наклонения применима к себе, а форма повелительного  - нет? Например: притворишься и притворись. Или относятся они к разным местоимениям? Сам притворишься, собой притворись. Поэтому не "ты врёшься", а сам врёшься, и ли ты сам врёшься.

Можно еще "рассказать поле+м"...

У "врешься" в стихотворении особое значение: пока самовыражаешься. Самовыража́ться. Глагол, несовершенный вид, непереходный
Раскрывать свой внутренний мир, душевное состояние каким-л. образом.  Или сочиняешь что.  То есть стараешься выразить, а там уж как получается)

Там должно быть "не рвись - пока рвёшься", а получилось врёшься. Ну и я про то, что у другой формы нет обращение к ТЫ-Я-САМ. То есть есть субъект-себя, есть объект-его, он, оно, она и тп, а есть личность-сам.

А я вижу тут игру слов, когда есть ожидаемое слово, а есть похожее, созвучное, но совсем неожиданное. А семантика уже потом. Семантика после додумывается, но сначала вот это.

Вы не поняли поэта) У него все на месте. Не прерывай логику повествования  (не рвись) в процессе творчества. // Он разговаривает сам с собой.   Обращается к себе и отвечает себе. В этом смысл диалога. (Кстати, у него вроде интересные стихи.)

Я не отрицаю, что вы говорите, но одно дело то, что вы думаете-чувствуете, когда смотрите на картину, а другое - что видите. Вот смотрите - цветы, кажется, а на самом деле хитро расположенные пятна даже не того цвета.

По-разному мы с вами видим)  Кто цветы, кто пятна)  Игра слов соответствует смыслу.

Не, цветы - вы думаете, что видите, вам кажется. А реально - это пятна. Художники они думают как бы двумя полушариями параллельно: одно видит пятна, а другое рисует цветы. В этом сложность, сочетать несочетаемое одновременно.

Вот что лингвистка написала:  Уникальную возвратную форму глагола врешься находим у А. Еременко – он образован от глагола врать, а возвратный постфикс –ся придает ему
семантику обращения действия на себя и в то же время самопроизвольности действия

От глагола врешь образовано + ся. А врать + ся - это враться. "придает ему семантику обращения действия на себя" - не уверен, что это грамотная фраза. "в то же время самопроизвольности действия" - а это просто не понятно). Ну да ладно, она права.

Пародия на стихотворение Ерёменко
(с грамматическим тропом)
Как чувства свои рассказать? 
В том мысли теснятся, как стаи:
Я знаю — что надо сказать, 
Расскажется как — я не знаю.

Процесс прохожденья к столу
Сомненья мои увеличит:
Там видятся буквы сквозь мглу,
Там кот спит и громко мурлычет.

По рельсу идти, по лучу?
По шагу идти, "понемножке"?
Но хочется сразу пройти
Туда по ковровой дорожке))

Пожалуйста, присылайте грамматические тропы или придумывайте их. Ваш вклад в современную литературу не останется незамеченным))

Я могу только сделать вклад, рассказав про любопытную книжку "Элементы антропоцентрической грамматики русского языка" (Русакова М.В.), правда это не совсем про тропы), хотя может быть тоже про тропы, но другие.

А где же рассказ?) Кстати, книги онлайн нет, так что трудно понять, есть ли там тропы. Вообще говоря, академичность специальной литературы не позволяет сделать тему популярной и доступной для широкой аудитории.

да, нет, нашёл на каком-то китайском серваке её) "академичность специальной литературы не позволяет сделать тему популярной и доступной для широкой аудитории" - да, это проблема, зачем вообще такие книги делать платными... целая проблема. В книге есть рассуждение почему слова могут менять одушевлённость, например слово "кукла". То есть вроде кукла одушевлённое, но ведь играть в куклы, а не в кукол. И на том же НРКЯ есть обе формы В.п. - одушевлённой формы и неодушевлённой. Ну и таких слов много. Я кусочек почитал только.

Сам тут думал, так как вопрос возник, в целом идея, что в языке есть проблема, для указания на человека или не человека - антропоцентричность, потому что человек-личность-субъект, а не человек - это предметы всякие, вещи. Это отражается в языке, в залогах и тп. В английском с этим несколько иначе, так как там есть категориальное деление, а в русском, много неопределенностей, однако в грамматике все чётко и понятно, и в зависимости от выбора окончания, понятно к чему это относится - к человеку или к вещи-абстракции.

И там ещё работа была какой-то аспирантки-иностранки, она сказала, что мол одушевлённость - это не столько грамматическая категория, сколько то, что нужно для обозначения "семантически пустых слов" - я так понимаю, что терминов. То есть например, слово мертвец - от мёртвый и человек, а труп - это мёртвое тело, тело основное слово, и тело - это термин, так как не несёт семантики, не указывает ни на что конкретное и ни на какую конкретную характеристику чего-то. А слово куклы может указывать как на игрушки-вещи - держу куклы, так и на (зависимого)человека, но тогда кукол.

Почитала в Википедии две статьи:  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Одушевлённость  и  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Активные_языки  Интересно!  Активный язык (фиентивный строй, активная типология, активность; лат. activus — деятельный, действенный) — язык, обладающий типологией, ориентированной на семантическое противопоставление не субъекта и объекта, как в языках номинативного строя, а так называемого активного и инактивного начал. В лексике активный строй проявляется в распределении существительных на классы активных (одушевлённых) и инактивных (неодушевлённых)...

Пережитком древнейшего активного строя в индоевропейском праязыке являлось деление существительных на «одушевлённый» и «неодушевлённый» (точнее — активный и инактивный) роды. Это деление есть в анатолийских языках, но в других языках индоевропейской семьи «одушевлённый род» распался на мужской и женский, к которым, со временем, было отнесено и большинство неодушевлённых существительных Остатком инактивного класса в современном русском языке является средний род. //   Итак, это пережиток))  Но он обозначен в грамматике, никуда от него не денешься.

О куклах. Они у нас активные и одушевленные по сходству с человеком. Но есть особые случаи: играть в куклы (в игру,  игра – неод.). Но вполне можно сказать: играть в кукол, представляя их одушевленными.

"Пережитком древнейшего активного строя в индоевропейском праязыке являлось деление существительных " - эх педивикия, педивикия... в этом она вся.

"Это деление есть в анатолийских языках, но в других языках индоевропейской семьи «одушевлённый род» распался на мужской и женский" - тоже не то. Я не знаю кто это пишет, но явно какие-то буратины.

Нет, это совсем не пережиток) И про разделение родов, у меня новые мысли появлись.

Вот умора! Значит, все неверно. Но мне понравилось про активные языки, ну и сама тема показалась интересной. Надо поизучать)

Нет, не так, это не то, чтобы неверно, но это весьма странное чтиво, это как спор круглоземельцев и плоскоземельцев, проблема что как-то подтвердить свою правоту достаточно сложно и той и другой стороне. И с другой стороны, это их взгляд на языки, с системой родов, одушевлённостями и тп, но через призму их языка. Они так это воспринимают и не врут, с их стороны это выглядит именно так. Ну или ладно, чуток преувеличивают "пережитком" нуну. Типа русский язык - это пережиток. А род - это не мужской и женский, а как раз мужской скорее отвечает за функционал, а женский за происхождение.

То есть пол - это вообще десятый смысл, деление на роды (или рода?) короче род не про деление на пол, а вообще про другое, более сложное и нужное, чем определение самка или самец. Мужской род - это признак или функция, а женский - это обычно родовые слова, что от чего зависит, что к чему относится. А средний род - это всякие понятия и термины, и прочие пустые слова.

Род и одушевленность – это прежде всего грамматически категории. Род – понятное дело, он в русском языке очень нужен, на нем строятся грамматические связи слов. Чем больше родов, тем точнее идентификация слов по грамматике, то есть больше определенности.  Англосаксам  этого не понять) А с точки зрения семантики эти понятия не так важны, и это в первую очередь касается одушевленности. Но история происхождения  этих категорий интересна.

Англосаксам этого не понять  - у них это решается иначе, и дает иной результат. "А с точки зрения семантики эти понятия не так важны, и это в первую очередь касается одушевленности." - в книжке в этой, как раз и проводятся исследования, что это не только грамматическая характеристика. Вы просто привыкли принимать это как должное и не задумываетесь о том, как это слово себя ведёт, а если встречаете неверное согласование, то поправляете. Но суть в том, что прежде всего это нужно для передачи определённых семантических сигналов. Про род не знаю, а про одушевлённость в этой книжке именно так.

"«одушевлённый род» распался на мужской и женский" - но судя по фразе, такое могло быть, и это связано с "типологией активности", например, вы можете понять, кто является субъектом действия, помимо возвратных окончаний. Кот прыгнул на стол, стол прыгнул на кот - уже не катит, на кота. Значит что-то меняется. Просто это весьма сложно отследить в голове(отрефлексировать), в какой момент это происходит, так как мы согласуем слова не задумываясь. А о функциональности и некой предикативности мужского рода, я пришёл, сравнивая мужские и женские названия животных и вещей.

Например молоток - это инструмент и звучит куда более определённо, чем мотыга. Мотыга - не ясно для чего, мотыжить, это как? Животные хищные или имеющие характерные отличия имеют названия мужского рода, а более обычные без явных признаков, не хищные, не опасные, имеют чаще названия женского рода. То есть выбор в названии рода связан с отношением с этим животным человека. То есть имеет место быть негласная классификация. И названия женского и мужского рода можно применять независимо от пола многие, потому что цель рода, указать на что-то ещё.

Грамматика - это отнюдь не пережиток, грамматика очень тесно связана с семантикой. И вообще меняет даже характер мышления людей. Вот в современном русском очень много терминов и терминологических связок, это делает язык более формальным, не таким "живым", каким он был раньше. Просто эта связка неочевидна, но познаваема в сравнении.
